Is there any mechanism in floating-point numbers when casting double to float?
While i study C#, i casted a double into a float by explicit conversion
int myInt2;
double myDouble3 = 13.1122217232323;
myInt2 = (int)mydouble3;

when it comes to the result, as myDouble3 changes the converted float differ.
It sometimes is rounded up and sometimes is rounded down. Why does it happen? Is there andy specific mechanism in explicit conversion double to float?
if the double is -13.135353535123514,
then the converted float goes -13.135353  // rounded down


if the double is 13.2323232323232323,
then the converted float goes 13.232324  // rounded up


From -13.135353535123514 to -13.135353, the numbers are negative, so it's rounded up.

What every computer scientist should know about floating point arithmetic - also see Is floating point math broken?

float or double converted to int will round (or truncate) towards zero in most languages derived from C. Converting from double to float will usually round to the nearest value which can be represented (I don't know much C#, whether it allows to control or is influenced by the active rounding mode of the CPU/FPU).

Does this answer your question? Is floating-point math broken?

The question @MatthewWatson links to is the answer to this question, to be honest. It explains deeply why this is.

That doesn't really answer the specific question, which is whether (float)(some_double_value) is documented to round up, down, toward zero, toward nearest, or some other rounding scheme.

Please, take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/numeric-conversions?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Converting a double to a float is most commonly done by selecting the nearest float value, although the C standard permits other methods, such as always rounding upward or always rounding downward.
With rounding to nearest, whether the result is higher or lower simply depends on whether the nearest representable float value is higher or lower.
